# Integrating with respect to a linear combination of two signed measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of X. Let $\mu, \nu$ be two real-valued signed measures defined on $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$ and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ Borel measurable, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone explain to me if the following takes place
$$\int f(x) d(\alpha \mu + \beta \nu)(x) = \alpha \int f(x) d\mu(x) + \beta \int f(x) d\nu(x)?$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. By definition if $E$ is measurable and $\mu(E)$, $\nu(E)$ are finite then
$$ (\alpha \mu + \beta \nu)(E) = \alpha \mu(E) + \beta \nu(E).$$

In integral notation this becomes
$$\int \chi_E d(\alpha \mu + \beta \nu) = \alpha \int \chi_E \, d\mu + \beta \int \chi_E \, d\nu.$$
From here you can prove the result for simple $f$ and from there for (sufficiently integrable) measurable $f$ via the usual limiting processes.

Answer (score -2):

Ok. Thanks for the reminder, Leucippus.

Dealing with this argument, as i said, you have to take care, because you don't know yet, if the monotone convergence theorem is still valid for signed measure.

Despite of this, we are able to prove this using only the definition of integral.

By definition,

$\int f d\mu := \sup \{\sum_{i=1}^N \inf_{E_i} \{f(x)\} \mu(E_i)\} \text{ ,}$

where the sup is taken over all partitions

But we already now that if $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\sup A+B = \sup A + \sup B$

So, applying the equallity above to $\int f(x) d(\alpha \mu + \beta \nu)(x) = \alpha \int f(x) d\mu(x) + \beta \int f(x) d\nu(x)$, we obtain the required identity.

Now, using the Hahn Decomposition Theorem you can prove the fact that te monotone convergence theorem also works for signed measures

Comment: This question already has an answer, and your answer makes things *way* too complicated.  For example, the monotone convergence theorem has nothing to do with this result.  As noted by Umberto P. (more than three years ago), the answer to the question follows almost immediately from the definition.

Comment: Hi, Xander. When Umberto said "usual limiting processes", was a clear reference to monotone convergence theorem. I'm not trying to be pedant here. I came here today with this doubt and in the moment that i found the answer, i went back here trying to explain why is not that obvious that the Umberto's solution really works. So i  was explaining why the referred "usual limiting processes" does not work with all clarity, because, indeed, you have to prove the monotone convergence for signed measures. I'll flag your comment for anyone supervise us.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that the "usual limiting process" in this case is the MCT.  It seems more likely to me that this is the usual [bootstrapping argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Constructing_the_integral)---prove the result for characteristic functions, then use that to prove it for simple functions, then nonnegative functions, then measurable functions.  Invoking the MCT here is circular, since you need to define the integral via this limiting argument before you can prove the more general result.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It is common for texts (Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, or Bartle's The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure, for example) to do that "bootstrapping" using MCT. For example, linearity of integration is proved that way in Rudin's and Bartle's books (ref: page 22 in Rudin, page 33 in Bartle). This is mostly due to convenience, related to how one defines things and the progression/order of statements that are proved.